# How do you make a texture that fits with the aspect fill scaleMode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scale, scene

I'm working on a universal ios device spritekit/swift game. I've run into a problem.
I have a 15x50 texture that needs to stay 15x50. So when I render the scene with the resize fill scale mode: the texture gets stretched vertically. But if I render the scene with the aspect fill scale mode: the textures are perfect but the scene itself is too big-the view doesn't show everything and elements that should be on the screen are way off. How do I tackle this problem? I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem so I'm feeling a bit lost.

Thanks yall.

Comment: use image twice the size and use aspect fill :)

Comment: If you want all the area is playable with a correct ratio, use aspectFit. This guarantees that the entire scene is visible but may require letterboxing in the view.